# what will be the translation vector unit from essential matrix

Tags: computer-vision, stereoscopy

from essential matrix, we may compute T and R matrix from it.
However, what is the unit of the T matrix? is the matrix in camera coordinate?

Comment: What do you mean by T matrix? We can obtain rotation matrix and translation vector from essential matrix using SVD, then the t is the vector in camera space.

Comment: SO THE T vector is the translational movement of the second camera from the first camera?

Comment: and how if when [u,s,v]=svd(E), the s(1,1) is not equal to s(2,2)? will it affect much?

Answer (score 3):

The essential matrix is only defined up to scale. When you decompose E into R and t, then t is also defined up to scale.  So its units are unknown, and it is often normalized to the a unit vector.

Answer (score 0):

The units of T are usually expressed in metres, but *can* be expressed in other units in theory. The focal length of the camera, which is part of the intrinsic matrix, encapsulates the relationship between the size of a pixel in the sensor and the units used for the extrinsic parameters. When you calibrate the camera, whatever units you use to specify the locations of known points (which could be the corners of a chessboard), the same units will be used in the essential matrix. The focal length also changes accordingly to reflect the correspondence between real world measurements and pixel size on the sensor.